# Spring Boot MongoDB Database Seeder w/ JSON file

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm wondering what the best to seed an initial MongoDB database with a Spring Boot application using JSON files. I have about 7 JSON files that need to be translated into 7 separate collections in the same MongoDB database. The JSON files are huge! Most of the examples I have found are for SQL databases, or show manually writing out each object in a seed file.

I'm currently using node to seed the database, then connecting the SpringBoot API to the already created database.

Any suggestions on how I could get rid of the Node DB seeder?

Answer (score 1):

you could try to use `mongoimport` (assuming the JSON data is clean)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/